# KeyError: 'variant' while getting data from API , even tho variant data exists on API

Tags: python, api

[Here is the API snippet. I am working on]

[image: 1]

Here is the code snippet that fetching API snippet above.

```
for i in parse_json["lines"]:
    list = []
    if (i["chaosValue"] > chaos_ex_ratio):
            value = (i["variant"],i["baseType"], i["exaltedValue"], "Exalted Orb", i["levelRequired"])
    else:
            value = (i["variant"],i["baseType"], i["exaltedValue"], "Chaos Orb", i["levelRequired"])
        list.append(value)
```

If I remove i["variant"] everything works perfectly but i["variant"] is throwing key error even tho "variant": "Shaper/Redeemer" exists on the JSON file. Thanks for any help.

Error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\emosc\PycharmProjects\GithubPushs\psychescape_price_fetcher\psychescape_price_fetcher\main.py", line 265, in <module>
    BaseType_Values()
  File "C:\Users\emosc\PycharmProjects\GithubPushs\psychescape_price_fetcher\psychescape_price_fetcher\main.py", line 219, in BaseType_Values
    value = (i["variant"],i["baseType"], i["exaltedValue"], "Exalted Orb", i["levelRequired"])
KeyError: 'variant'
```

Comment: I think the issue might be that variant does not always exist. Since you are looping over all the items in lines some of the items don't have an influnce/fracture/synthesis to be tagged as a variant and that value might not exist. (I recognized the data from PoE so i'm guessing that this is your issue). I would add a check for variant before you try to append it to your value

Comment: Yeah that is probably the problem. Thanks Karan!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're showing us a screenshot where the *first* line has a `variant`, but your code will fail unless **every** line has a variant.

What is the output of this snippet?

```py
for l in parse_json["lines"]:
    if "variant" not in l:
        print("Line {} does not have a 'variant'".format(l))
```

If it outputs any lines, there's your problem. If it doesn't, something deeper is going on. I would try to catch the `KeyError` exception and put a breakpoint in the handler to continue investigating.

Comment: It prints a hell of things. How can I check lines if variant exists or not for every input?

Comment: @CanerÇetin in your for loop just add `if 'variant' in i :` then include it in your value and add an else clause to exclude it

Comment: It's right there in my snippet; you can check on any given line with the expression `"variant" in l` which evaluates to `True` iff that particular `line` object has a `variant` attribute. You would only attempt to dereference it in that case.

Alternatively, you can use `l.get("variant", "default")` to avoid `KeyError`s altogether, it'll just return `"default"` when `variant` is missing. (This just replaces `i["variant"]` in your code above)